# How do I add client-side attributes to items in a FirebaseListObservable?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm building a simple chat app backed by this Firebase Database structure:

```
messages: {
  "-KTjL_oLrKOboa2su2zk": {
    name: "puf",
    text: "Look I'm smiling :-)"
  },
  "-KTjNfaNem752ChFBcnC": {
    name: "puf",
    text: "And now I'm not smiling"
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular2 and AngularFire2 to generate the HTML. I have a simple list of messages from the Firebase Database in my controller:

```
export class AppComponent {
  messages: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.messages = af.database.list('messages');
  }
}
```

I want to detect certain conditions in each message and translate that into an emoji in my HTML. Since this is purely display information derived from the existing content, I don't want to store it in the database.

My HTML template:

```
<li class="text" *ngFor="let message of messages | async">
  {{message.name}} {{message.emoji}}: {{message.text}}
</li>
```

In the Firebase JavaScript SDK, this would be akin to:

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var message = snapshot.val();
  if (message.text.indexOf(':-)') >= 0) {
    message.emoji = '';
  }
  addMessageToHTML(message);
});
```

How should I do such client-side enrichment in AngularFire2?

Comment: Is the question how to get data from FirebaseListObservable or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. The best I can say is that I want to add a property to each object from the FirebaseListObservable, so that I can display that property in my HTML (which I just added that to the question).

Comment: I updated the answer with working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how things work in JSSDK, but when you subscribe (with `async` pipe) to `FirebaseListObservable` you are disconnected from Firebase (upstrem); you will still get updates (downstrem). So you can just chain `map()` to the observable, and add property in the client:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

export class AppComponent {
  messages: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.messages = af.database.list('messages')
      .map(messages => messages.map(message => {
        if (message.text.indexOf(':-)') >= 0) {
          message.emoji = '';
        }
        return message;
      }))
  }
}
```

UPDATE: [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2t4Mf7Ny7Sb7RxY0p5L4?p=preview)

If you update data with 3rd record on the server side, template should update. You can't however add new message to the `this.messages` on the client, you have to recreate reference and update the server that way:

```
    af.database.list('messages').push({
      name: "new",
      text: "Now I'm sad :-("
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since asking, I've indeed been looking to use a `map()` (I have no need to add/remove items, just change them). But somehow I can't invoke `map()` on the FirebaseListObservable: `af.database.list('messages').map(message => {...` gives `Property 'map' does not exist on FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`

Comment: You have to import it explicitly, it's not on `Rx.Observable` by default. Add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` somewhere early in your app; top of the root `app.module.ts` for example.

Comment: AngularFire2's `list` emits an array value - it doesn't flatten the array content - so you'd need to use `Array.prototype.map` inside your RxJS `map`.

Comment: Wouldn't `Array.prototype.map` consume the entire stream?

Comment: Great to see the working plunker btw. I had tried the nested `map()` calls, but wondered if that was the problem. Seems it was not. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time implementing the same approach in my (equally simple) app. The TypeScript compiler keeps finding faults, mostly due to `map()` not being defined on `FirebaseListObservable`.

Comment: Never mind, I'm blind. I missed your `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`. Adding that did the trick. Thanks for the help!