# ctorParameters.map is not a function - AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to use Firebase with Angular 2, to get the position of a person and display it on a google maps. And every so often, the position must change in real time.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.2",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.9",
    "gentelella": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28-3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

I run `npm update`, then `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`, `npm cache clear`, `npm install -g angular-cli@lastest`, But it does not work for me. When I activate `AngularFireModule` in my `app.module.ts` it gives me the error of:

```
Reflection_capabilities.js: 58 -> Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function (...)
```

This is my app.module file:

```
[..]
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
[..]

export const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "...",
 authDomain: "abc.firebaseapp.com",
 databaseURL: "https://abc.firebaseio.com",
 storageBucket: "abc.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "48515646ABC"
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I update? When I run npm update, I get no message.

Comment: Did you import the map operator? I had that mistake when starting with Angular2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984247/how-do-i-add-client-side-attributes-to-items-in-a-firebaselistobservable

Comment: same here. it happened yesterday. and i didnt event start to use firebase.
when comment AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
all goes ok.